# How to open an .xls file in an excel add-in starting with the right mouse click in the Windows folder

Tags: windows, vba, excel, contextmenu, regedit

Probably what I'm trying to do is difficult, perhaps impossible, so I ask for your help.
I have created an Excel add-in (which I call MyAddIn.xlam) that does some operations on Excel files '97 -03 (reports exported from third-party software). For example a MyDoc.xls file.
I would like MyAddIn.xlam to modify MyDoc.xls simply by starting from a right click of the MyDoc.xls icon.
My questions are:
1. How can I add a "Edit with MyAddIn" voice for .xls extension to the context menu of Windows 10? (i think in regedit)
2. What and where do I have to write to let MyAddin.xlam open? (i think in regedit)
3. In VBA how do I resume the name of myDoc.xls file previously clicked?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want, but if we start somewhere perhaps we can get there. So, we start with this code. It adds a button to the context menu. Paste it to a normal code module.

```
Option Explicit

    Const ButtonID As String = "MyCustomTag"

Sub DelContextControl()
    ' 28 Apr 2017

    Dim Ctl As CommandBarControl
    Dim Del As Boolean

    Do
        Set Ctl = CommandBars("Cell").Controls(1)
        Del = (Ctl.Tag = ButtonID)
        If Del Then Ctl.Delete
    Loop While Del
End Sub

Sub SetContextControl()
    ' 28 Apr 2017

    Dim Cbar As CommandBar
    Dim Cbtn As CommandBarButton

    Set Cbar = CommandBars("Cell")
    Set Cbtn = Cbar.Controls(1)
    If Not (Cbtn.Tag = ButtonID) Then
        Set Cbtn = Cbar.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , 1)
        With Cbtn
            .Tag = ButtonID
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .BeginGroup = True
        End With
    End If

    With Cbtn
        .Caption = "My own button"
        .OnAction = "MyMacro"
    End With
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()

    MsgBox "I respond to your command"
End Sub
```

The code starts by defining an ID for the control. You can use any unique string but, once decided on it must not be changed because the code uses it to identify your button, and if it is lost you will also lose control over the button.

Next comes a macro which deletes the button. In case you created the same button several times it will delete all instances of it. But it will only delete buttons having the set ButtonID and found at the top of the list, because that is where the next procedure will insert it. Always run this procedure before you change the `ButtonID` in the code.

The third procedure inserts a button at the top of the context menu and identifies it with `ButtonID`. At the bottom of this procedure you will find the properties for `.Caption` and `.OnAction`. You can change both. The `OnAction` property has the name of the macro which should run when the button is pressed.

You can now create the button, try the button and delete the button. But what you want the button to do I don't understand. Perhaps it is better to make that another question anyway because this chapter is both long enough and complete within itself. I hope it is a part of what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry i was looking for creating a Shortcut Menu Handlers "Modify with MyAddIn" in Windows 10 64bit